# Keras ConvS2S why use len(input_texts) in the prediction?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, seq2seq

I'm running the ConvS2S example, the model trains just fine, but the inference code it's not clear enough, why does the prediction arrays have the length of the inputs_texts? My predictions output gibberish, I'm clearly doing something wrong, since my model seems to learn quite, well.

Thanks in advance.

As far as I can tell the prediction array should be something like:

The original source is this:

```py
nb_examples = 100
in_encoder = encoder_input_data[:nb_examples]
in_decoder = np.zeros((len(input_texts), max_decoder_seq_length, num_decoder_tokens), dtype='float32')

in_decoder[:, 0, target_token_index["\t"]] = 1

predict = np.zeros((len(input_texts), max_decoder_seq_length), dtype='float32')
```

But why use `len(input_texts)`?

Comment: You may want to add a pointer to the seq2seq example you are referring to. There are multiple implementations out there. The way I read your code snippet input_texts is an array / sequence of phrases; if that is the case then you would want a prediction for each sentence thus the output would be shaped as (number of sentences, sentence length).

Comment: The example is this one in the Keras-Examples: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/cnn_seq2seq.py

Comment: input_texts is a list with all input examples, my question is why is that needed for inference?

Comment: len(input_texts) is actually wrong. It should be nb_examples. It doesn't really matter because the predict variable gets overwritten in the prediction loop.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is answer is really good thanks, I'm doing some testing right now with these changes.